# Hiding columns from datagrid when autogenerate=false

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I create columns in codebehind as such.. each column is bound to a property.

```
Dim column_selected As New DataGridCheckBoxColumn()
column_selected.Header = "Selected"
column_selected.Binding = New Binding("IsChecked")
dgvResults.Columns.Add(column_selected)
```

I want to be able to hide a column, based on a checkbox or something of that nature, where I can hide/show them at will.

I've heard about binding visibility to a property Boolean, but i'm not sure how to do that when the columns are created in code behind.

Any idea on how to accomplish this? Say I want to have a single checkbox that hides a specific column, if you unchecked it, it shows it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If logic of setting column visibility doesn't contains any business logic and this is clear UI operation.  Then I think you can just put it in the code-behind, what is wrong with that?

XAML

```
<CheckBox Checked="HideColumn" Unchecked="UnhideColumn"/>
```

Code-behind

```
Protected Sub HideColumn()
    'your code
End Sub

Protected Sub UnhideColumn()
    'your code
End Sub
```

Comment: How do I reference the binding name though instead of the index? They can move columns around so that might be bad.

Comment: You can find index of column in runtime `datagrid.Columns.ToList().FindIndex(Function(column) column.Header.Equals("YourHeader"))`

Answer (score 1):

You can set Binding normally from code-behind, but since System.Visibilty is enum, you have to use Converter (an instance of `IValueConverter` interface) to set Binding correctly. There are a lots of possible implementation, the following is an example:

```
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool? vis = value as bool?;
        return (vis.HasValue && vis.Value) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

After that, the only thing you should do is to set the Converter property of your Binding to the new instance of `BoolToVisibilityConverter` as follows:

```
column_selected.Binding.Converter = new BoolToVisibilityConverter()
```

And that's all.